# Why I can only retrieve current location when already having permission?

Tags: android, kotlin, location, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I want to handle something in my ViewModel whenever the current location retrieved. But it didn't work at the first time I start the app and approve the permission. Only be able to see some logs after I close and start the app again.

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        locationRepository.location.collect {
            Log.d(TAG, it.toString())
```

My repository to connect the location data source as you can see

```
class LocationRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val dataSource: LocationDataSource,
    @ApplicationScope private val externalScope: CoroutineScope
) : LocationRepository {

    override val location: Flow<MapLocation> = dataSource.locationSource
        .shareIn(
            scope = externalScope,
            started = WhileSubscribed()
```

And the final is LocationDataSource where I put the logic to get the current location.

```
class LocationDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val client: FusedLocationProviderClient
) {
    val locationSource: Flow<MapLocation> = callbackFlow {
        val request = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(4)
            fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(4)
            priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }

        val callBack = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(result)
                result.lastLocation?.let {
                    trySend(it.asModel())
                }
            }
        }

        //Subscribe to location changes.
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, callBack, Looper.getMainLooper())
        awaitClose { client.removeLocationUpdates(callBack) }
```

Comment: Someone please help me, this is link to my github project for better code know: https://github.com/orpfodnegen/weather-app

Comment: Not super familiar with location, so this is going to be a comment rather than an answer, but what I'm guessing is happening is that your call to `locationRepository.location.collect` ends up erroring out because it is called before your app has location permissions. A way to verify that would be to add a CoroutineExceptionHandler to the scope that collect is called in (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler) and log any exceptions that occur

Comment: Thank for you comment. I found out because I still used deprecated onPermissionResult on my fragment so although I launch the scope after permission aprrove it didn't do anything. Replace it with the new val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult solve my problem.

Comment: Could you guide me how to highlight those code locationRepo... in the comment. Is it git markdown

Comment: Yes, for the code highlighting like I've got, you use the `\`` character like this `\`<code here>\``.
Also, if you've answered your own question, feel free to submit your solution as an answer (comments aren't indexed by search engines).

Comment: Thank for your guide. I think I should learn more about markdown to write some readme file for my personal project well. I gonna submit the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is I still did use the `onPermissionResult()` in my fragment, so after switch to the new `requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult`, and call `onForegroundPermissionApproved()` instead of in init of ViewModel, after approve the location permission. Everything work properly.